# Why am I getting org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Request header too large

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, spring-webflux

I have the following WebClient configuration in a spring boot reactive service:

```
public WebClient createWebClient(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies
        .builder()
        .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
          clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().enableLoggingRequestDetails(true);
          clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(
              new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
          clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(
              new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        }).build();

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory) {
      @Override
      public Request newRequest(URI uri) {

        Request request = super.newRequest(uri);
        request.timeout(requestTimeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return requestLogEnhancer.enhance(request);
      }
    };

    httpClient.setMaxRequestsQueuedPerDestination(maxRequestsPerDestination);
    httpClient.setMaxConnectionsPerDestination(maxConnectionsPerDestination);
    httpClient.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeoutInMilliSeconds);

    WebClient.Builder webClient = WebClient
        .builder()
        .clientConnector(new JettyClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .exchangeStrategies(strategies)
        .defaultHeader(HTTP.USER_AGENT, USER_AGENT_VALUE);

    return webClient.build();
  }
```

This WebClient is used for API calls to other services.

The service was running fine for more than a month but 1 of the instances suddenly started getting the following exception:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Request header too large
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.process(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP.sendHeaders(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.send(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP$Delegate.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.succeeded(HttpDestination.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool.proceed(AbstractConnectionPool.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$1.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$1.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Promise$Wrapper.succeeded(Promise.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onOpen(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onOpen(SslConnection.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.connectionOpened(SelectorManager.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1800(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:889)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.BufferOverflowException: null
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:521)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.putSanitisedValue(HttpGenerator.java:932)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.putTo(HttpGenerator.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateHeaders(HttpGenerator.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:250)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

After restarting the service, this exception didn't happen anymore but I am afraid this might happen again. What could be the root cause for this exception? How can this be reproduced and resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that when attempting to set a Header Value, the value would exceed the configured output buffer.

What is your configured output buffer size?

By default the HttpClient.requestBufferSize is 4096 bytes.

If that seems sane, then also, check your HttpClient to ensure it's not picking up extra Cookies.
The Jetty HttpClient will use the JDK CookieStore / CookieManager and those will remember Cookies for quite a while, sometimes far longer than you expect.  An excess of Cookies can also trigger this error as you have no room left for your headers if you have a ton of Cookies being automatically added.